# How can I get Mongo sub-document in a List in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

My current mongo document has this structure :

```
{
    "rating" : 3,
    "comment" : {
            "id"   : 1,
            "text" : "Average food"
    }
}
```

And currently my Java POJO class is :

```
public class RatingObject {
    Integer rating;
    Comment comment;
}
```

Till now I was allowing user to select only one rating comment. I am now allowing my users to select multiple rating comments. Now since my `comment` field will be an array of objects, can I change my Java POJO class to have `comment` field as an `List<Comment>` so that while retrieving old mongo objects I will have only one element in the list and where as while saving the new ratings I will save a list of comments as list ? As in :

```
public class RatingObject {
    Integer rating;
    List<Comment> comment;
}
```

**The question is, can I just change in my Java class and save the situation here ?** Because just changing the Java class will leave my old mongo documents inconsistent with this Java class definition.

PS : I tried doing this already but I get this error:
`Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments`

Comment: Sure you can. What exactly is the question?

Comment: @shmosel Changing the mongo structure is working for me but that seems a really bad idea to me. I did this:
`db.ratings.find().forEach(function(doc){doc.comment = [doc.comment];db.ratings.save(doc);})`

Comment: You'll need [converters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters). [Here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-index-annotations-converter) is an example.

Comment: @ares This POJO is just a sample. My actual Java class has lots of other fields which I set in my service class. Will I have to again set all these fields to DBObject when I will write a RatingWriteConverter ? And same when I am writing a RatingReadConverter, will I have to read all the fields again ? Can't I just focus on `comment` field and read/write all other fields as is ?

Comment: Yes since your schema is not cosistent across all your documents, you need to write custom converters. If spring has a support for dynamic schemas natively, then I'm not aware about it.